# defining firewalld permissions without SELinux in Debian

Tags: debian, permissions, firewalld

I don't find an explanation regarding the permission system of firewalld in Debian without SELinux. I have multiple users. How do I grant one user admin permissions to firewalld while denying these to the others without giving root access? Thought of a group like lpadmin.